# time complexity of the following three loop dependent condition

Tags: time-complexity

Can anyone find me the big O notation of the following code?

```
 sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i*i;j++)
            {
                 for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
                      sum++;
            }
    }
```

Comment: O(n^3) is the time complexity